# Edit AppTheme in Run Time, How can i do it programmatically without XML-code?

Tags: android, xml, colors

I have the following problem:

There is response with json-array, which contain colors settings from the server. And from difference companies difference settings. There are next colors:

1) A main color, it serves to fill background;

2) A second color, which highlights a text, icons and buttons on the background;

3) The color, the darker the first - used in the allocation;

4) The color that is used for coloring the boundaries of the text and icons, if 1st color matches with the 2nd;

(It is the analogy with colors on iOS, because we write native applications and have on server)

And I do not know whether you can manually set these colors in Theme for the entire application , or this configuration must be stored in the form of a XML-code, i.e. we need to write a parser that generated an xml-string (it is a difficult way for me =))? 
In addition -  if I want to change the Theme of entire application, how can I do this better programmatically? One way I know - all my activities inherited from class, which extends a class Activity, and in this class prescribe and change the Theme. Maybe there are other ways? But the main question about the generation of style.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no clean and direct way to do this.  The theme is part of the resources which are generated at compile time.  And Resources.Theme is a final class, so it can't be overridden to do custom behaviors.

So the options you are left with are all bad:

- Brute-force change each and every visual property of every widget affected by the customer theme. Yuck.
- Dynamically create HTML pages that can be read into a WebView and used as the UI instead of Android widgets.  You will probably have to write a lot of canned JavaScript code that will be part of this web UI.
- The cleanest, but nearly impossible way, would go like this:  As each customer gets registered in your corporate database (along with their color branding scheme), your build process generates a new expansion APK with a theme for that customer, then uploads it to Google Play. Your app would need to know to look for an updated expansion APK and get the user to download it (which may not always happen), then your JSON response would give you the customer name or whatever you need to determine which theme to pull from the expansion APK.  Finally, your app would set the theme on the Activity for your white-label UI.  So many things would have to happen correctly that it would be a minor miracle if your user saw your customers' corporate branding colors.  But just thought I'd mention the idea for inspiration.